# Setting the multiple JREs in the same application

Tags: java

I have implemented one application using JDK 1.6 **64-bit**, JSF, Tomcat server **64-bit** etc at user system.I am integrating  some *devices*(i.e. finereader, scanner, etc) into this application. Some of devices libraries are supported only on JRE **32-bit** Only.

So, device integrated screens to be run on **JRE 32-bit** and non device screens should be run on a **JRE 64-bit**. Can I configure multiple JRE's in the same application? If possible, how?

Comment: If your core dependencies are in 32-bit, what would make moving to 64-bit so important?  Conversely, if you can find support for your core dependencies in 64-bit, why not upgrade those?

Comment: device relevant libraries are internally used .dll files.For example TWAIN Drivers are implemented 32-bit only.So we need to run 32-bit JRE.But my user wants application should be run 32-bit as well as 64-bit?

Comment: It is not possible this way. The JVM is running in a sandbox, it is not possible to spred your application between two JVM (without some advanced technics)

Comment: Is there any alternatives way?

Answer (score 0):

A Java application runs in a JVM. The JVM is part of one single JRE. You could split your application into two parts, which each run in their own JVM. These applications then would have to communicate with each other to coordinate the user experience. This does not look like a good solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you define "application."

First, in regard to your question, each JVM instance runs a single kind of Java--32 or 64 bit--Java version and such.

Sometimes, an application consists of a single JVM running a single java executable, usually a jar and some stuff on the classpath with a single 'main'

Sometimes, an application consists of multiple JVMs running on one or more boxes. In this case, each JVM is running a single java executable. But there has to be some sort of communication between these executable parts to make it function as an application.

Alternatively, the same executable might run on multiple JVMs and we still call it one application. In this case, there would be some sort of outside stuff that decides how to allocate the work of the application amoung the multiple JVMs. For example, you could run 18 instances of Tomcat on 9 boxes with a hardware load balancer dividing up the network requests and assigning each one to one of the Tomcat instances. In this case, though, part of the application is probably running on 1000's of user's computers inside a browser.

Sometimes, we say multiple applications are running under another application. In this case, we might call the master application a container. One example is Tomcat. In this case, Tomcat manages the load of requests for each of the separate applications because the HTTP requests come in off the network with information in the header indicating which one handles that request.

You already say that you have some code running under Tomcat. Tomcat is a single executable (It runs in one JVM and has one variety of Java) and it manages running your one Java executable supplied as a .war file, usually. There could be other Java applications running in other JVMs that communicate through that Tomcat and with your executable. Or there might not be other JVMs that your executable communicates with running somewhere else.

So, you can see, the real answer is "it depends." If you have multiple JVM communicating in some way, you could have different Java varieties. If it's all running under a single Tomcat instance, then you have a single variety of Java.

Comment: Can i configure multiple JVMs share with Tomcat instance?.

Comment: One Tomcat instance runs in one JVM. One JVM has one variety of Java.